# Error inserting android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: result.high (code 1299)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert, android-logcat

I keep getting this error each time i try to insert radio question, value, and answer retrieved from sqlite in asset folder.

```
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting yans=24 question=com.example.tochukwu.myapplication.Question@ecb77c9 exp=24 hours makes a day
              android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: result.high (code 1299)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:798)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1502)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1373)
                  at com.example.tochukwu.myapplication.ExamDBHelper.insertDataUser(ExamDBHelper.java:133)
                  at com.example.tochukwu.myapplication.Ges100Activity$2.onClick(Ges100Activity.java:184)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6199)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23235)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1073)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
```

ExamDBhelper

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_RESULT + "("
            + COL_0
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + COL_1
            + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + COL_2
            + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + COL_3
            + " TEXT NOT NULL)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_RESULT);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

I'm using constraint values

```
public boolean insertDataUser(String question, String  yans, String exp){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1,question);
    contentValues.put(COL_2,yans);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,exp);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_RESULT,null ,contentValues);

    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Button click activity

```
 boolean isInserted = db.insertDataUser(
                    currentQ.toString(),
                    currentQ.getANSWER().toString(),
                    currentQ.getEXP().toString() );
            if(isInserted == true)
                Toast.makeText(Ges100Activity.this,"Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(Ges100Activity.this,"Data not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Every other thing is working except for the insert value.
each time i try insert using the onClickButton i get these error on the logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line :-
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: **result.high** (code 1299)

Is indicating that the NOT NULL conflict is on the column named **high** in the table named **result**.

You insert, inserts into columns **yans**, **question** and **exp**, to not have the conflict you need to supply a value for the **high** column. Or alternately alter the structure of the table.

Perhaps the root cause is that you have changed the structure, by removing the **high** column from the SQL invoked in the `onCreate` method, not realising that the `onCreate` only runs once for the lifetime of the database and that any structural changes need to either force `onCreate` to be run, or alter the table (you'd can't directly remove a column using alter, you'd have to create a differently named table using the new structure, copy any existing data from the original to the new table drop the original table (or rename it) and then rename the new table with the original name).

If any existing data can be lost then the simplest fix is to do one of the folllowing :-

- delete the App's data (deletes the database).
- uninstall the App (deletes the database).
- increase the version number (drops the table and invokes the `onCreate` method)

After doing one of the above rerun the App.

Comment: thank you very much..I;m grateful. it's working now.